# Is there a way to join two tables and then group by some attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have two tables Emp_774884 and Dept_774884.

Emp_774884 contains

```
emp_id  ename  sal  deptid
```

Dept_774884 Contains

```
deptid dept_name no_of_emp city
```

I have tried this following query to find the employee with highest salary from every department.

```
select emp_774884.ename,Max(emp_774884.sal) as salary, dept_774884.DEPT_NAME
from emp_774884 join
      dept_774884
      on dept_774884.deptid = emp_774884.deptid
group by dept_774884.DEPT_NAME ;
```

But i am getting the following result

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:
*Action:

I am expecting to get the following columns grouped by their department name

ename salary dept_name

Comment: Isn't there a closing bracket missing? Please remove postfix numbers, Dept_774884 could be Dept or Department, that number only makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear -- you have columns in the `select` that are unaggregated and not in the `group by`.  Merely adding the columns makes the error go away, but doesn't do what you want.

Oracle has a very nice extension called `keep`, which does what you want:

```
select d.DEPT_NAME, max(e.sal) as max_salary,
       max(e.ename) keep (dense_rank first order by e.sal desc) as ename_at_max
from emp_774884 e join
     dept_774884 d
     on d.deptid = e.deptid
group by d.DEPT_NAME ;
```

Note that this returns only one employee name when there are ties.  It is not clear what you want in this case.

Comment: I want to divide the table by department name and then print the ename of each department who have highest salary

Comment: Above query did the part what i exactly what i wanted. But only one thing is wrong in that emp_774884 doesnt contain dept_name, at last line it should be d.dept_name. Thank You. Can u explain me what it is doing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

**Query what you want**

```
select e.ename,d.DEPT_NAME, Max(e.sal) as salary, d.DEPT_NAME
from emp_774884 e join dept_774884 d on ( e.deptid = d.deptid)
 join (select dept_774884.DEPT_NAME, Max(emp_774884.sal) as salary, dept_774884.DEPT_NAME
from emp_774884  e1 join
      dept_774884 d1
      on d1.deptid = e1.deptid
group by dept_774884.deptid) t on (e.deptid = t.deptid)
```

Now come to the point. Why you are getting

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression" *Cause:
*Action:
```

So this exception come when you use group by exception with some column and at the time of select you use different columns.

In other words

You can only select those columns which you mentioned in group by.

So in your case you use deptid as group by column but you are select other column too.